# Running Oprofile with MPI

Tags: bash, mpi, oprofile

I'm having issues using Oprofile to profile a parallel program that I call via `mpirun`.  The command I'd like to use is:

```
    $ operf mpirun -n 4 [program and arguments]
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, operf starts logging, but something funny happens when the MPI program is finished - `operf` seems to not recognize that it's returned (MPI-spawned processes no longer appear in `htop`, but `operf` still does), and things just hang waiting for me to interrupt them.

Is there an option I can pass to `operf` or `mpirun` which will make the two play nicely together? Failing that, is there a bash trick I can use to automatically kill `operf` when my MPI program is finished?

**Edit:** Previously thought that it Oprofile wasn't always generating results, but it turns out that I was just confused and looking in the wrong location. The only problem is that operf doesn't recognize that the MPI program has terminated.

Comment: Is your MPI job running on one node (i.e. single operating system instance) or multiple?

Comment: Did you try running "mpirun ... operf [prog + args]"? That might be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line, it works like a charm:

```sh
sudo operf mpirun --allow-run-as-root -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH="build/" -np 2 (path_to_the_file)
```